# How to sum the lengths of a collection in F#?

Tags: .net, f#

I'm trying to print the total number of lines for all files in a given directory. However, I get an error `Type mismatch. Expecting IEnumerable<string> -> 'a but given a 'b list -> 'c list`. I'm not sure why this is. Here is my code:

```
let printLengths path =
    let files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
    let fileLengths = files |> List.map (fun dir -> Seq.length(File.ReadLines(dir)))
    printfn "%i" (List.sum fileLengths)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles` returns a [sequence aka `IEnumerable<'T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/sequences-%5Bfsharp%5D), not a [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/lists-%5Bfsharp%5D). Use `Seq.map` and `Seq.sum` to map or sum sequences.

Or, for a shorter solution, use `Seq.sumBy`:

```
let printTotalNumberOfLines path =
    Directory.EnumerateFiles path
    |> Seq.sumBy (File.ReadAllLines >> Seq.length)
    |> printfn "%i"
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and improved solution :)

Answer (score 3):

You are using `List.map` on `files`, but the output of `Directory.EnumerateFiles` is an `IEnumerable`. `List.map` works on `list`s only. You could try using `Seq.map` instead, or convert `files` first with `Seq.toList`.